# Какое оптимальное колличество корзин для BucketSort?

Tags: java, сортировка

Пытаюсь написать хороший `bucketsort` для семестровки. Из всего нагугленного на этот вопрос экспериментальным путём отвечает один пользовательна [хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/335920/).
Есть ли какое-либо обоснование оптимального количества корзин для данной сортировки?

Answer (score 0):

Среднее время работы bucketsort (k-количество корзин)

```
O(n + n^2/k + k)
```

Отсюда следует, что для обеспечения линейной сложности k должно быть порядка n. Из разумных ограничений памяти выбирают `k=n/c`, где c - некая константа. Вот её и стоит подобрать для конкретной реализации.